# MSBuild Condition IsDebug

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msbuild-task, targets

How can I determine if a project is build in Debug (or Release) mode within an MSBuild .targets file and use this information as a condition for another property?

Something like:

```
<OutDir Condition="IsDebug">bin\Debug\$(SomeOtherProperty)\</OutDir>
<OutDir Condition="!IsDebug">bin\Release\$(SomeOtherProperty)\</OutDir>
```

Is there such thing as Debug/Release mode, or are they just conventional *names* for different sets of configuration properties' values?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Debug/Release or whatever are just conventional values for the `Configuration` property.

So, as long the project that includes/calls your .targets file adheres to the convention; you can check for debug mode as follows:

```
<OutDir>bin\Release\$(SomeOtherProperty)\</OutDir>
<OutDir Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' ">bin\Debug\$(SomeOtherProperty)\</OutDir>
```

or you could just use that variable directly:

```
<OutDir>bin\$(Configuration)\$(SomeOtherProperty)\</OutDir>
```

Comment: Well the problem is that I have 8 configurations, half debug and half release. Their names of course are not 'Debug' or 'Release' but conventionally i have named them 'Debug <something>' 'Debug <somethingElse>' etc. So instead of a == check I would probably do a Contains check right?

Comment: Exactly. Depending on the complexity of your targets file, it may be useful to either introduce the `IsDebug` property from your example, or an `ConfigurationType` (or similar) property having the value *Debug* or *Release*.