# Release mode for one project in solution, but Debug mode for all others

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have 10 projects in Visual Studio solution. There is a requirement to run all projects in DEBUG mode. I want to configure only one project to be run in RELEASE mode (need performance boost). Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on Solution then choose Configuration Manager. You can change build type for every project in solution.

More information can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx).

Comment: Hmm I'm stupid :) It will be enough to set checkbox on 'Optimize Code' in project properties?

Comment: They are other settings that are changed too e.g. availability of `DEBUG`  symbol and generation of debug info (this option can be seen after clicking Advanced button on Build tab in solution properties).

Comment: Also some MsBuild task may use `Configuration` property that will be not set to Debug by simply enabling 'Optimize Code'. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800726/msbuild-condition-isdebug